# Safari does not connect to aliased hostname on localhost via https

Tags: webpack, https, safari, localhost, certificate

Since the most recent Safari update I cannot connect to my local React apps via `https` on localhost via **local domain aliases** anymore. However, I can access them via `https://localhost:<someport>` but **domain aliases** result in a

> Can't connect to the server

error. It used to work flawlessly in the past... → Safari.

#### My Setup

```
// hosts

# The classic
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost

# Local dev aliases
127.0.0.1 some.local.com
::1 some.local.com
```

I've also created **certs** via `mkcert`

```
$ mkcert -install
$ mkcert "*.local.com" localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

This seemed to work, since I do not get any `https` security warnings on Chrome or FF anymore.

```js
// webpack.config -> devServer

...
server: {
  type: "https",
  options: {
    key: readFileSync(resolve(__dirname, "../certs/_wildcard.local.com+3-key.pem")),
    cert: readFileSync(resolve(__dirname, "../certs/_wildcard.local.com+3.pem")),
    ca: readFileSync("<output of mkcert -CAROOT>/rootCA.pem"),
    requestCert: true,
  },
},
...
```

#### Summary

- I do not think it has something to do with the certs since it works perfectly on **Chrome** and **FF**.
- It did work BEFORE updating Safari recently...
- In Safari: I can connect to my app via `https` using `localhost` instead of the domain alias but unfortunately this is not an option

Any ideas? Any tips much appreciated!

Comment: which version of safari worked, and what is your current version?

Comment: @benc thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I do not know which version I had previously but now I have `v16.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found an answer even though not very satisfying.

Apple has shipped the new Safari Version (17.0) with [http/3](https://blog.cloudflare.com/speeding-up-https-and-http-3-negotiation-with-dns/) automatically activated for "some" users. So it seems that I was one of the chosen ones but could also not find any option to disable http/3 in order to run some proper tests.

However, it seems that http/3 ignores lookups for domains listed in `/etx/hosts` and thus no custom domain aliases for `localhost` will work.

So my solution is running all my apps via `http://localhost`.